# Rails doesn't work in one directory, but does everywhere else

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Terminal output:

```
(^_^) - (vagrant@ubuntu) - (jobs:0) - (~) - (531) 
----> rails

/// Bunch'O Rails stuff, clearly installed ///

(^_^) - (vagrant@ubuntu) - (jobs:0) - (~) - (531) 
----> cd -
/home/vagrant/Development/ksaa

(^_^) - (vagrant@ubuntu) - (jobs:0) - (~/Development/ksaaa) - (532) 
----> rails
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Why would this happen? Rails works everywhere, except in this one directory (/home/vagrant/Development/ksaa).

### /home/vagrant/Development/ksaa:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 app
drwxr-xr-x  5 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 config
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant  154 2013-04-11 17:57 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x  2 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 db
drwxr-xr-x  2 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 doc
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant  932 2013-04-11 17:57 Gemfile
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant 3.6K 2013-04-11 17:57 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x  8 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant  434 2013-04-11 17:57 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  4 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 log
drwxr-xr-x  2 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 public
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant  269 2013-04-11 17:57 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant 9.1K 2013-04-11 17:57 README.rdoc
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant   15 2013-04-11 17:57 .rspec
-rw-r--r--  1 vagrant   24 2013-04-11 17:57 .rvmrc
drwxr-xr-x  2 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 script
drwxr-xr-x  3 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 spec
drwxr-xr-x  7 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 test
drwxr-xr-x  4 vagrant 4.0K 2013-04-11 17:57 vendor
```

---

Comment: Can you provide a full directory listing?

Comment: Will do. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [have an `.rvmrc`](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/) file that means while you're in this folder, you're using a different Ruby (and Gem) version than the system one. This will be one installed through RVM.

I'm fairly certain that in this case, you don't have a Rails Gem yet. Verify this with `gem -v` and `gem list`, once run from your directory, and once from anywhere else. You should see different Gem versions.

You should be able to install the Rails Gem simply by running `bundle install`, which looks at the Gemfile and installs everything that's missing.

If you *do* have a Rails Gem in your project's Ruby version (the one from RVM), then something's wrong with your RVM configuration. You should however be able to start the Rails server through `bundle exec rails`.

Comment: Would upvote, but I can't.

Comment: No worries. Once you have enough reputation you can upvote :) Welcome to Super User!